# Use of flashing font/marching ants to direct attention to question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

My current question currently has 4 (!) votes to close for being unclear. In its very first iteration, it had a paragraph that began with "My question is...", and even explained the question two different ways for those who might have trouble understanding! It nonetheless received two votes to close.

I have since bolded, italicized, explained in comments and done everything I can think of to draw attention to the question, and yet I received two more votes to close for being unclear. My question is one vote away from being removed despite bending over backwards to prevent and then mitigate this issue.

***My question is:*** Can we somehow enable the old-school Microsoft Works blinking text, or if not, the early-90's crawling-ants border? I'm running out of ways to redirect people to my question.

Comment: I've read through your question several times and can see why it is being marked as unclear. Even though you've bolded the question, the question itself is confusing. It's not unclear what you are asking, it's just a very confusing question. I don't think a blinking border around the question is going to help, you will probably need to explain it further.

Comment: Is your "current" question [Neutral, science-based Undead](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/107896/29)? You've asked [another question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/108249/29) since, which seems to have been fairly well received out of the little attention it's gotten so far...

Comment: This refers to the neutral undead question, correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not commenting on your question on the main site, but on your proposal here:

> Can we somehow enable the old-school Microsoft Works blinking text, or if not, the early-90's crawling-ants border?

**To this, my answer is no, no, no, *please* in the name of all things holy, no!**

Blinking text is absolutely *horrible* UX. Animations aren't much better.

If you somehow manage to work blinking text into a post, and I come across it, then you can almost certainly expect to recieve a downvote for that reason alone...

Comment: Trolling pro-tip; ask a question in a UX forum, using Comic Sans font. I worked with a UX guy who actually had a poster up on his wall; Friends don't let friends use Comic Sans. I can't comment on whether the soft copy of the poster employed blinking or sparkle text, though.

Answer (score 4):

More for other readers than to the OP: [the question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/107896/21222) is not unclear.

It explicitly says, in bold, and I quote:

> **given what we currently know of the science of the human body, what change would require the smallest number/magnitude of handwavium/magic inputs to reach my end goal of a not-necessarily-evil undead-like state?**

And then it elaborates on what is required in the answers:

> I'm defining undead-like state as (by order of importance):
>
> - immortality (primary quality)
> - slow external decay/deformation (secondary quality)
> - classic undead drives/desires like brains/blood/flesh (tertiary quality)

I think someone voted to close as unclear before any edits, and other users followed suit. Please read the whole question before voting to close, when you see it in a queue.

---

Regardless, it has a bounty on it now. It is going to receive some extra attention, and until the bounty is awarded, it cannot be closed.

Comment: *"Please read the whole question before voting to close, when you see it in a queue."* **Yes.** Please! Same with any other review activity. Always make up your own mind based on what you're actually seeing, not how other people coming before you have acted.

Comment: *Please read the whole question before voting to close*; not only in the review queue, but in the newest questions queue too. Not every question is well written, they need close reading to make sense of them. The OP tried to provide extensive information about the context & additional careful reading was required. Don't assume every comment on a question is right. This rarely happens.